# Why does it give me the error 'too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Tags: c

I've only started to learn how to program a few days ago and i am following a tutorial. every time i go to compile my code I get "too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]"

Ive tried re-writing the code but it didnt help.

```
int main()
      {       
             printf("i\n" ,radius);
             return 0;
       }
```

The error was:

```
too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there are too many arguments for format; nothing in the format string is preceded by a `%`, so it doesn't take *any*.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience but what is a format string ? The format of the variable is an integer meaning i have to put a %i ?

Comment: The format string is the string that defines how you want the output formatted.  It is the only string in your posted code.

Comment: Yes , 'Radius' is  declared as an integer and i want it to be output as an integer when i print it.

Comment: I see i was missing ' % ' In order to format it as an integer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
         printf("%i\n" ,radius);
         return 0;
   }
```

You have to use '%' + letter depending of type of variable

Comment: Within the printf() function?